# Getting ClassNotFoundException for Facebook exception Class referenced from facebook4j jar

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to build a facebook connector using facebook4j jar.
Whatever I have coded is working fine if I run the classes from eclipse directly, but if when I am trying to create a jar file of my connector which has facebook4j jar as well, and use it in some other Project, I am getting below error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: facebook4j/FacebookException
    at FacebookMain.main(FacebookMain.java:18)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: facebook4j.FacebookException`

I am creating jar file from eclipse only and have checked below option

> Export generated class file and resource

Any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: You understand what `NoClassDefFoundError` mean?

Comment: what I know is that the .class file of the FacebookException class is not getting generated in the generated jar file. But I am not understanding why only for the Facebook Exception class it is happening.

Comment: How are you adding the Jar file to your project? Added it to class path or build path?

Comment: "Some other project" needs to refer to both your code and facebook4j.  This is what dependency management is for